# Escape comma when using csv writer

Tags: java

My application writes the data from Jtable to a csv file.

I use the below function:

```
public static boolean exportToCSV(JTable RnRFetchTable,String pathToExportTo) {
    try {
        DateFormat writeDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
        Date writeDate = new Date();
        TableModel model = RnRFetchTable2.getModel();
        FileWriter csv = new FileWriter(new File("C:/Users/Desktop/TableExport" + writeDateFormat.format(writeDate) + ".csv"));
        for (int i = 0; i < model1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            csv.write(model1.getColumnName(i) + ",");
        }
        csv.write("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < model1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < model1.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                csv.write(model1.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + ",");
            }
            csv.write("\n");
        }
        csv.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Export Successful!");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! Excel cannot be exported!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code works fine when one of the columns don't have the comma, but when it does, the delimiting happens wherever the "," comes. How to write the csv by escaping comma?

Comment: The proper way to escape commas in a CSV file is to put double quotes around that field. Why aren't you using a standard CSV-writing library?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values - while this looks simple, special cases can be tricky.  Please use a library as suggested by @RealSkeptic

Comment: @Jayan @RealSkeptic My requirement is not to use any external libraries, hence using the old-school method here. I know i have to tweak `excel.write(model1.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + ",");` part and/or `excel.write("\n");` but dont know and stuck here.

Comment: You need to come up with a method to convert any string to a safe "csv" content.  If this is for learning, you can read opencsv (github?) code and see relevant sections.

Comment: You may also want to use `writeln();` instead of `write("\n");` to write platform specific line endings.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround your text with double quotes:

```
csv.write("\"" + model1.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + "\",");
```

Comment: But then you also need to escape quotes in the fields.